# Making a fast Mandelbrot Fractal viewer

Tags: java, performance, mathematics, javafx, fractals

I'm making a Mandelbrot set viewer in JavaFX. It takes a while, like maybe 5 seconds to finish.  Here's my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private static int MAX_ITER = 80;
    private static double w = 10*100;
    private static double h = 2*Math.PI*100;

    static double RE_START = -2;
    static double RE_END = 1;
    static double IM_START = -1;
    static double IM_END = 1;

    public static int mandelbrot(Complex c) {
        Complex z = new Complex(0,0);
        int n = 0;
        while (Complex.abs(z).isLessThanOrEqual(2) && n < MAX_ITER) {
            z = Complex.add(Complex.multiply(z,z),c);
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Mandelbrot Viewer");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, w, h));
        primaryStage.show();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        canvas.setWidth(w);
        canvas.setHeight(h);
        canvas.relocate(0, 0);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        update(gc);
    }

    private static void update(GraphicsContext gc) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                Complex c = new Complex(RE_START + (x / w) * (RE_END - RE_START),
                        IM_START + (y / h) * (IM_END - IM_START));
                int m = mandelbrot(c);
                int hue = 360 * m / MAX_ITER;
                System.out.println(hue);
                int saturation = 255;
                int value = 0;
                if (m < MAX_ITER) {
                    value = 255;
                }
                gc.setFill(Color.hsb(hue, saturation/255d, value/255d));
                gc.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static class Complex {
        double r;
        double i;

        Complex(double r, double i) {
            this.r = r;
            this.i = i;
        }

        static public Complex abs(Complex c) {
            return new Complex(Math.abs(c.r), Math.abs(c.i));
        }

        public boolean isLessThanOrEqual(double n) {
            if (r <= n || i <= n) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        static public Complex add(Complex c1, Complex c2) {
            return new Complex(c1.r + c2.r, c1.i + c2.i);
        }

        static public Complex multiply(Complex c1, Complex c2) {
            return new Complex((c1.r*c2.r)-(c1.i*c2.i), (c1.r*c2.i)+(c1.i*c2.r));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return (r + ", " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

I eventually want it so that I can move around and zoom into the mandelbrot set with at least 10 fps.  How might I be able to make it faster?  Should I try switching from JavaFX to AWT or something?  Should I try using the GPU? if so, what would be the most simple way to do so? (because I don't really want to spend too much time on this project)

Comment: How many instances of Complex class do you create per frame?

Comment: From a frustrated benchmark (can't seem to get an execution profile), almost *no* time is consumed by `mandelbrot()`. (I *doubt* that the instantiation rate of small instances forgotten before the next is instantiated currently impacts time (for the record, `Color`s get instantiated frequently (less of a problem) and set for `gc` (more of one)).)

Comment: Thanks. Looking more closely the problem is writing single pixels using the fillRect function. Instead of operating on GraphicsContext create an array of integers to represent the image. There's a lot of info in StackOverflow about how to do that.

Comment: Should I try using BufferedImages and draw them on the canvas instead? would that help? @greybeard

Comment: That seems to be what [SuperFractalThing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/suprfractalthng/) uses - I have never been up to speed with Java performance graphics.

Comment: FYI. Fields of `Complex` could be `final` (as could the class itself arguably) but I imagine that the Java runtime is bypassing heap allocation of this class entirely because it can see it is used/discarded immediately. This is "escape analysis": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136040/performance-of-javafx-gui-vs-swing

Comment: [This](https://github.com/james-d/ZoomingMandelbrot) is quite old and uses a `WritableImage` for the display. I didn't use a complex number representation, which helps with some optimization (caching the squares of the re and im parts, for example). It also parallelizes the computation. This achieves the frame rate you're looking for (except, of course, for very deep zooms). It could probably be made faster/cleaner using the new (JavaFX 13) support for pixel buffers.